# get the actual device orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiinterfaceorientation

Working on an ios app and i am trying to figure out how to get the actual device orientation even if the app is fixed in portrait mode. At the moment all orientation checks are giving me portrait. This is what I have checked.

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation2 = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

Basically I want to know the orientation a photo is taken in but if the camera picker is loaded up in portrait and phone is turned to landscape after that the result orientation of photo is portrait. I was hoping to be able to check the actual device orientation at moment the photo was taken and transform it accordingly.
Any ideas on how to approach this?

edit: I am going to look into using the gyro for this will report back how that goes.

edit: sorry i should have mentioned that the phone itself is in fixed portrait orientation.but is there a way of getting around that to see what it actually is

Answer (score 0):

Pass your captured image to this function & it returns the image with the orientation which you captured it.

```
- (UIImage *)fixOrientation:(UIImage *)myImage 
{

    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (myImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return myImage;

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (myImage.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, myImage.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, myImage.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            break;
    }

    switch (myImage.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, myImage.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, myImage.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(myImage.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(myImage.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(myImage.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (myImage.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,myImage.size.height,myImage.size.width), myImage.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,myImage.size.width,myImage.size.height), myImage.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}
```

Comment: thanks but the image orientation of myImage will always be UIImageOrientationUp as that is what the device thinks it is in when app is in a fixed portrait mode. I have already tried this function so I am very sure that it is always giving result of UIImageOrientationUp

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIDevice`'s `orientation` property

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

It returns you physical orientation of device.

[ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4)

Comment: afraid i tried that too    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]; gives me UIDeviceOrientationPortrait when i hold the phone in landscape while taking image